# Query to find all matching rows of a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the column containing my row entries for `skills`

```
C,C++
P,H,D
ASP,.net,C,C#,C++,R+
C++
```

I need to find all entries that contain `C`. So I formatted a query by using `Skills LIKE ('%'+@Skill+'%')` and this gives me all entries including `C++` when I just want to get the result of `C` alone.

Searching from the above example, I must only get `C,C++` and `ASP, .net, C, C#, C++, R+` rows. I must not get `C++` - last row in the resultset.

My requirement is that I need to get only `C` when searching for `C` and not `C++`. How do I format such a query?

I am using stored procedures to execute all the queries.

Comment: You need to normalize your database structure.

Comment: This is yet another reason why you should aviod storing data in a delimited string. Move skills to a new table and this problem will go away (along with multiple other problems you might not even be aware that you have).

Comment: I am totally clueless about normalizing database structure. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I do have Skills in another table, but I do not know how to search by index values by linking back from this current table.

Comment: @Rai http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter based on these conditions

1. if search skill is first skill in column `Skills LIKE @Skill +',%'`
2. if search skill is any where in the middle `Skills LIKE '%,'+ @Skill+',%'`
3. if search skill is at the end  `Skills LIKE '%,' + @Skill`
4. if search skill is the only skill `Skills = @Skill`

**Query**

```
SELECT ...
WHERE Skills LIKE '%,'+ @Skill+',%'
OR Skills LIKE @Skill +',%'
OR Skills LIKE '%,' + @Skill
OR Skills = @Skill
```

**EDIT**

Another shorter query can be

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ',' + Skills + ',' LIKE '%,'+ @Skill+',%'
```

***Note:**: You may face performance issues with such a design and query. If possible look into creating a skills table to hold all skills for a user. Please see Zohar Peled's answer on how to improve your design*

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks a lot! I do need to point out that whitespaces will bring this query format down.

Comment: Nice job explaining the workaround, not so nice ignoring the actuall problem. Keeping comma delimited strings in a database is a problem and you know it. I will upvote your answer if you would have elaborate on that.

Comment: @Rai - When storing csv as in your case, there are a lot of pitfalls and loopholes which can come out. white spaces like you mentioned, or if `,` is part of a skill etc etc will fail in such a design. as Zohar mentioned, these sql are based on your current design and structure which itself if not optimal.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - you are correct that the design is flawed and we do need to point it out to the user, however schema change may not be an option available to everyone.

Comment: @ughai I do agree that using `,` is not the best way to store data. I have covered the whitespace problem by having a jquery function that prevents space as input. I guess I need to fix anything that might happen as I find more pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

Use these conditions

```
Skills LIKE '%C,%' OR Skills LIKE '%C' OR Skills = 'C'
```

Comment: & What if 'C' is stored alone ?

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is stored as a delimited string you will have to use workarounds like the answers you already got.
After a quick glance most of them will answer your question, meaning that you will be able to search for a specific skill, However none of them provides a solution to the problem, only a workaround. It's like using a bandaid to plug a hole in a boat.
What you actually should do is normalize your database, meaning that instead of keeping the skills as a comma delimited string, you should create a skills table, with only one skill per record, and a personToSkill table that will hold a unique combination of personId and skillId. This Is the correct way of handeling many to many relationships in a relational database. Of course, you will need a unique constraint on thd skill, as well as foreign keys between each relates table.

Comment: I understand this, but right now I am looking for a brute force approach to finish my task at hand.

Comment: You can take my advice or ignore it, it's your database, not mine. I just want to give the best answer I can. There might be other people that will benefit from it, and I personally believe that now that you have that knowlede, even if you don't use it now, you will benefit from it in the future.

Comment: I will take up the many to many mapping in the next phase of this application development, as it is due for delivery at a very short notice. And it is a pity that I can only upvote your answer one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (name varchar(50))
insert into @t (name)values ('C,C++'),('P,H,D'),('ASP,.net,C,C#,C++,R+'),('C++')

select * from @t where name like '%C,_%'
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the pupose of `_` before `%`?

Comment: actually here we are filtering records basing on c but if we give %% it will include C++ so i have given %C,_% then it will eliminate C++ look for only C,C++ or C,C# what ever @Rai

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`Skills  = 'C' OR Skills  Like '%,C%' OR Skills  Like '%C,%'` in `WHERE` condition

Answer (score 0):

```
set @skill = '%'+@skill+'%';
select * from table where skills like @skill
```

Comment: This is what I have already tried in my query, which did not give me the expected answer