# SQL server not returning all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the procedure that I am using to search for skills from a single column. There are 3 variables that I need to pass to the `SP` and I need to get the results accordingly. I do understand that searching for multiple values from a single cell with a delimiter is prone to errors, but this query is not working after I tried to put the whole thing within another `IF ELSE` condition.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spFilterThisResume]
@Skill varchar(100),
@Exp INT, @Dt date
AS
DECLARE @NoStart INT
IF (@Exp = '')
    SET @Exp = NULL
IF (@Dt = '')
    SET @NoStart = 1
BEGIN
DECLARE @SkillId varchar(100)
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',')
OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @SkillId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    IF (@NoStart = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tblResume
        (Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)+',%' OR Skills LIKE (@SkillId)+',%' OR Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId) OR Skills = (@SkillId)
        AND (Experience LIKE @Exp))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tblResume
        (Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)+',%' OR Skills LIKE (@SkillId)+',%' OR Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId) OR Skills = (@SkillId)
        AND (Experience LIKE @Exp)
        AND (CreatedDate LIKE @Dt))
    END
END
    PRINT @SkillId
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @SkillId
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

The result I got before I tried to put this into `IF ELSE` block was accurate. It returned even a single occurance of a single skill that I passed as parameter. But I do not understand which part of the query messed up the whole resultset that I got earlier. I unfortunately did not save the working `SP` into a notepad. So please help me to identify what mistake I made.

NOTE: `SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',')` is a function that I am using to split the input `csv` into its component arguments

Comment: when using `AND` and `OR` together, always use `(` and `)`. enclose all `OR` conditions in `()` like this `WHERE (Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)+',%' 
        OR Skills LIKE (@SkillId)+',%'
        OR Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)
        OR Skills = (@SkillId))
        AND Experience LIKE @Exp
        AND CreatedDate LIKE @Dt`

Comment: you can even shorten the multiple `ORs` to something like this `',' + Skills + ',' LIKE '%,'+ @Skill+',%'`. I updated the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30660446/4436237) to your previous question with this even simpler sql

Comment: @ughai I have added opening and closing braces, but I still get the same resultset.

Comment: what is your updated sql?

Comment: check my answer on why you are getting incorrect results. Refer to the answer by GarethD on how to re-implement your code without using cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going wrong is that your begin and end blocks are all out of line, and you end up in an infinite loop. If I remove actual queries, and add in a comment for each bit to shorten it, and label each begin/end with a number to tie them up you have:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spFilterThisResume]
AS
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
BEGIN                                       -- 1 BEGIN 1
    -- DECLARE CURSOR AND OPEN IT
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN                                   -- 2 START WHILE
        IF (@NoStart = 1)
        BEGIN                               -- 3 START IF
            -- QUERY WITH NO DATE CHECK
        END                                 -- 3 END IF
        ELSE
        BEGIN                               -- 3 START IF
            -- QUERY WITH DATE CHECK
        END                                 -- 3 END IF
    END                                     -- 2 END WHILE

    PRINT @SkillId
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @SkillId
END                                         -- 1 END 1

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

So your second `FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @SkillId` falls outside of the `WHILE`. So you never update `@@FETCH_STATUS`, it will always be 0 after the first fetch, and you will never exit the loop to get to the second `FETCH`, to correct it you would need to just put your second `FETCH` inside the loop.

However, this is needless use of a cursor, and as a general rule you should avoid cursors as much as possible. You could just use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblResume AS r
WHERE   r.Experience LIKE @Exp
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',') AS s
            WHERE   ',' + r.Skills + ',' LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'
        );
```

This uses your original split function still, but in a single query, so imagine, as from your previous question you have rows in Resume:

```
C,C++
P,H,D
ASP,.net,C,C#,C++,R+
C++
```

And you pass `C++,C#`, rather than running the query twice, once for `C++` and once for `C#` you can run the query once checking for each value, the exists clause essentially expands out to:

```
SELECT  
FROM    tblResume
WHERE   r.Experience = @Exp
AND (   ',' + r.Skills + ','  LIKE '%,C++,%'
    OR  ',' + r.Skills + ','  LIKE '%,C#,%'
    )
```

Also, since `@Dt` is a `DATE`, the check `@Dt = ''` is really checking if `@Dt = '1900-01-01`` which is unlikely to be required behaviour? I suspect you want:

```
IF @dt IS NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT  *
    FROM    tblResume AS r
    WHERE   r.Experience LIKE @Exp
    AND     EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',') AS s
                WHERE   ',' + r.Skills + ','  LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'
            );
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT  *
    FROM    tblResume AS r
    WHERE   r.Experience LIKE @Exp
    AND     r.CreatedDate = @Dt
    AND     EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',') AS s
                WHERE   ',' + r.Skills + ','  LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'
            );

END
```

i.e. Checking where the date is not passed, rather than when it is 1900-01-01.

```
        ----
```

**ADDENDUM**

With regard to why you need to use the predicate as follows:

```
WHERE ',' + r.Skills + ',' LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'
```

Again, using some of your previous example data (an one extra row):

```
1. C
2. ASP,.net,C,C#,C++,R+
3. C++
```

So if you were just looking for 'C', you might use:

```
WHERE r.Skills LIKE '%C%';
```

But as you noted in your previous question, this would also yield row 3 because `C++` is like '%C%', which is not correct, it is therefore necessary to look for `%,C,%`, i.e. where there is a complete match on the skill:

```
WHERE   r.Skills LIKE '%,C,%';
```

This would now mean that the first row is not returned, because `C` on it's own is not like `%,C,%' - therefore we need to put the delimeter at the start and end of`r.Skills` to ensure that the first and last terms in the list are not excluded from the search.

If you pass NULL for `@Exp` you would get no rows returned since the predicate `[Anything] = NULL` yields `NULL`, so will never be true. This is not just the case in my answer, it is the case in your question too.

Comment: I am a beginner in SQL, could you please explain me how my query is wrong? And also explain how your query works?

Comment: One minor change on your `WHERE`, it should be  `',' + r.Skills + ',' LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'`.

Comment: @ughai, yep, thanks, spotted that whilst doing my latest edit.

Comment: if you can add the bit on why OPs `WHERE` clause structure with `AND` and `OR`  leads to incorrect results, I am happy to delete my answer.

Comment: The `SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@Skill,',')` function returns the `csv` as a single column. So how do I search for each row in the column?

Comment: I get that, I am not sure how best to explain how [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) works, you may be best off reading the documentation. Essentially after the split has been done the exists clause will check each row to see if there is a match in tblResume, it is a similar principle to your cursor, but much more efficient.

Comment: Can you explain why you have formatted this part of the query, `WHERE   ',' + r.Skills + ',' LIKE '%,' + s.Value + ',%'` with the leading and trailing `','` to enclose `r.Skills`? What difference does it make when you have the query without such `','`?

Comment: Can you also please tell me how the query will execute when I pass `NULL` value for the Integer argument? I have understood how the Date argument works.

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct, though I still would like get explanations for my above questions please.

Comment: I have answered your above questions in my edit 5 hours ago, everything below the bold header **"ADDENDUM"**.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is returning incorrect results because you are using `(` and `)` to wrap both `AND` and `OR` together.

You need to structure your query like this.

```
SELECT
 * FROM tblResume
WHERE
(
    Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)+',%'
    OR Skills LIKE (@SkillId)+',%'
    OR Skills LIKE '%,'+(@SkillId)
    OR Skills = (@SkillId)
)
AND (Experience LIKE @Exp)
```

**Note:***As mentioned in the answer by GarethD, you can avoid the use of cursor in such a case.*

Comment: If I structure it this way, I am not getting any resultset at all even though there are not exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Does `@Exp` contain wildcard characters? `LIKE` does an exact match same as `=`

Comment: No, `@Exp` is just integers

Comment: In your case `Experience LIKE @Exp` is same as `Experience = @Exp` because `@Emp` doesn't have any wildcards like `%` or `_`